# Nuitka can't open the .py file for compiling it

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

[So I have previously used nuitka to create standalone executables for my python scripts and had no issue until this time I tried once again]

I am trying to use nuitka to create a .exe file for my .py script however, it throws the following error:

```
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation.
__main__.py: can't open file 'MyPythonProgram.py'.
```

I have given the following command in the command prompt (run as administrator and in the correct directory):

```
nuitka --mingw --follow-imports MyPythonProgram.py
```

I have also tried using `--onefile --windows-onefile-tempdir` and `standalone` however the result was the same.
I am using python 3.9.4 and nuitka 0.6.14.4. (Same as last time when it actually worked without throwing any errors)

So let me know, what went wrong with my attempt and how to fix it...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `/full/path/to/MyPythonProgram.py` ?

Comment: Yes, the issue persists

Comment: NOTE: The issue is now fixed somehow after I renamed the file and renamed it back again.

Comment: maybe you had `space` in name or other char which is not visible - or you had char which looks similar to other char but has different code.

Comment: Yes, I probably think that's the problem. Thanks for your time.